# Yaml step has invalid name

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am migrating/integrating an existing Azure DevOps Release to Azure DevOps multistage pipeline.

When exporting each task as YAML and pasting it in the pipeline, I encounter an issue with the step name:

> Step qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens has an
>   invalid name. Valid names may only contain alphanumeric characters and
>   '_' and may not start with a number."

This is the YAML:

```
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
            displayName: 'Replace tokens in appsettings.json'
            inputs:
              rootDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/tokenize'
              targetFiles: appsettings.json
              actionOnMissing: fail
```

What can be done to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full name is optional. The YAML wizard does generate it by default. You can probably replace the task name to:

```
replacetokens@3
```

Or

```
qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens@3
```

To fix the pipeline. The `replacetokens-task` bits are the contribution-id and I filed a bug with the team some time ago that it shouldn't be part of the generated YAML as it can cause issues. A fix should be rolling out at some point.

Comment: And the task author can't change the contrib ID without breaking all current task users. Pretty nasty problem as an author. Don't ask me how I know ;).